How do I insert linebreaks for coefficient names in modelsummary()
Is there a way to force line breaks in coefficient labels in latex output from modelsummary?
Inserting a <br> and fmt_markdown will work for gt output, but not when the document is a pdf.
---
title: "Test"
format: pdf

---

```{r}
library(modelsummary)
library(gt)
var1<-rnorm(n=100)
var2<-rnorm(n=100, mean=5)
variable_number_3<-sample(c("red", "blue"), size=100, replace=T)
df<-data.frame(var1, var2, variable_number_3)
mod1<-lm(var1~var2*variable_number_3)
modelsummary(mod1, coef_rename=c("var2:variable_number_3red"="var2\\\\variable_number_3red"), output="latex") 

UPDATE:
I tried manually setting the column widths for a gt() table.
---
title: "Test"
format: pdf

---

```{r}
library(modelsummary)
library(gt)
var1<-rnorm(n=100)
var2<-rnorm(n=100, mean=5)
variable_number_3<-sample(c("red", "blue"), size=100, replace=T)
df<-data.frame(var1, var2, variable_number_3)
mod1<-lm(var1~var2*variable_number_3)
modelsummary(mod1, coef_rename=c("var2:variable_number_3red"="var2xvariable_number_3red"), output="gt")  %>% 
cols_width(1 ~ px(50))

But this returns the following latex error on compilation:
<to be read again> 
                   p
l.240   &
          (1) \\ ```




<br> is an html tag correct? Is there a latex equivalent to that?

Yes, usually it is \ or \newline, but it appears inserting line breaks in tables is quite hard.
